# Check for a private http call

Tags: http, nestjs, typescript-decorator

I'm trying to make a private http call made in NestJS version -> 9.4.2. I need to verify that through the call there is some kind of custom decorator (I've read the nest documentation I didn't get an approach) to compare it to a .env variable to check if the call it is permitted or not, I share my actual call:

```
 @Post('/login')
  async login( @Body() body: AuthDto) {
    try {
      let usuario: IUser[] = await this.loginService.getUser(body);
      const tokens = await this.authService.getTokens(usuario);
      return tokens;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new BadRequestException('Something bad happened', {
        cause: new Error(),
        description: 'Some error description',
      });
    }
  }
```